# Change list items to name R

Tags: r, list

I have a lot of lists that look like this

```
:List of 73
..$ :List of 2
.. ..$: chr "aaaa"
.. ..$: num 2
..$ :List of 2
.. ..$: chr "cccc"
.. ..$: num 7
..$ :List of 2
.. ..$: chr "dddd"
.. ..$: num 5
..$ :List of 2
.. ..$: chr "bbbb"
.. ..$: num 6
```

et cetera for 73 times

So there are 73 lists within the list. And each part of those lists contain of two items. But in fact it is one item and the second itemis the value. How can I change the list in an automated way so that it looks something like this:

```
:List of 73
$ aaaa: num 2
$ cccc: num 7
$ dddd: num 5
$ bbbb: num 6
```

et cetera for 73 times

I have a lot of lists looking like this, but each time the "aaaa" is on a different place, so changing manually is very time consuming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each element `x` of `mylist`, you can access the first sublist with `x[[1]]`; and the second with `x[[2]]`. This function can also be called as `` `[[`(x,i) `` where `i` is the number of the sublist.

```
mylist    <- list(list("aa",2),list("cc",7))
str(mylist)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "aa"
#   ..$ : num 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ : chr "cc"
#   ..$ : num 7
mynewlist <- setNames(lapply(mylist,`[[`,2),sapply(mylist,`[[`,1))
str(mynewlist)
# List of 2
#  $ aa: num 2
#  $ cc: num 7
```

`setNames(x,xnames)` just returns `x` with its elements labeled with `xnames`.

---

**Not using a list.** You probably do not need a `list` and can work with a vector, which is simpler:

- In my answer, switch the `lapply` to `sapply`.
- In ColonelBeauvel's, remove the `as.list` call.

Accessing its elements by name is fairly intuitive:

```
myvec <- setNames(sapply(mylist,`[[`,2),sapply(mylist,`[[`,1))
myvec["aa"]
# aa 
#  2
```

Comment: @Gianni Glad to hear it! Just added a section to the answer as you were commenting -- you might want to consider using a named vector.

Comment: @Gianni, if this resolved your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark to its left below the vote total.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use an approach without `lapply`. If `lst` is your initial `list`:

```
x = unlist(lst)
setNames(as.list(as.numeric(x[seq(2, length(x),2)])),x[seq(1, length(x),2)])

#$aaaa
#[1] 2

#$cccc
#[1] 7
```

**Data:**

```
lst=list(list('aaaa',2), list('cccc',7))
```